# Is there a way to unit test a simple directive declaration in AngularJS? (no link function)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I have a simple directive definition like this

```
function computeTotals() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: 'compute-totals.html',
    controller: 'ct as ctrl',
    scope: {},
    bindToController: {
      property: '=',
      numbersArray: '='
    }
  };
}
```

How would I go about unit testing to make sure this directive is set-up correctly?  I just want to verify these properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a way to get it easily and not sure if it will break in some condition. But I tried the below code in my spec and may be you can give the try for your expectation and provide the feedback.

```
    let componentName = 'dummyComponent';
    let directiveName = 'dummyDirectiveName';
    let templateUrl = 'dummyTemplateUrl';

    var details = angular.module(componentName)['_invokeQueue'];

    var directives = details.filter(detail1 => detail1[1] === 'directive');

    var directiveInfo = directives.filter(y1 => y1[2][0] === directiveName );
    var result = directiveInfo[0][2][1]();
    console.log('TESTTTT ',result);

    expect(result['templateUrl']).toEqual(templateUrl);
```

Comment: @Jack Johnson, did it helped in any way?